# ffmpeg scaling images for Instagram (640x640)

Tags: image, ffmpeg

I'm trying to scale a Image with the original size of width: 634px and height: 845px to 640x640 for Instagram upload.

Tryed this

```
ffmpeg -i 1.jpg -vf scale=w=640:h=640:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease 2.png
```

But i get width: 480px and height: 640px. How can i add some white sidebars to bring the image back to 640x640?

Answer (score 0):

Add the [pad filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad):

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf "scale=w=640:h=640:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=w=640:h=640:x=(iw-ow)/2:y=(ih-oh/2):color=white" output.png
```

Comment: Worked like a Charm. Thank you :)